# Android Application how to save Imageview in gallery

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app. This app can drag&drop image to an image.My problem is how will I save the Image that I show in the imageview? In 
here i used 2 imageview.

Comment: what code have you done so far? share the relevant one

Answer (score 0):

Usually you already have image that you show as file or in-memory model.

That would make this question not dependent to Android IamgeView.